Tests are running in parallel, despite all parallel options being turned off
I'm using Visual Studio 2022, latest version, on .NET 6.
All test classes are marked with [Collection("Sequential")].
I'm running a single test from within Test Explorer (right click, debug test). Run tests in parallel menu item is disabled.
And yet, all tests are actually running in parallel.
I can tell this because my tests clear out test data and re-seed the database, before each test is run. When I run a single test, I can watch the database delete and re-insert data, so all the other tests are running in the background.
I'm pretty sure this has only just started happening in either the last or previous VS updates.
Is there anyway to turn this off, so that when I run 1 test, only 1 test runs?

All your tests are running when you right click a single test? All as in all test classes in your project?

@mxmissile Correct.  Test Explorer doesn't show that happening, but I can see externally that it IS happening.

In case anyone else has this issue:
I had an extension called 'Fine Code Coverage', that was executing the code in the background.
